# Converting a list of tuples of different sizes into a dictionary

Tags: python, data-structures

I have a list of tuples and want to turn this list into a dictionary. However, the tuples can be larger than 2 and not the same size. I would like the first element of each tuple to be the key and the rest to be stored as a array for the value.

```
l = [(1,'a','b'),(2,'c'),(3,'d','e','f')]
```

Just doing `d=dict(l)` doesn't work (didn't really expect it to). I would like to use a list comprehension along of the lines of  `d = dict([(k,v) for k,v in arr])` but allow for v of arbitrary size.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Winston Ewert has the best (most portable) answer. As an alternative — if you have a recent version of Python — you can use dictionary comprehensions:

```
d = { t[0]:t[1:] for t in arr }
```

Answer (score 8):

```
d = dict( (v[0], v[1:]) for v in arr )
```